# TextBlock with text highlighting

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Faced the need to select a fragment of text in TextBlock, namely certain keywords on which the ListBox was filtered, this text block itself and containing
XAML variant, title property is not bound

```
<ListBox Name="ProcedureList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProceduresView.View}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                 <StackPanel Name="ProcedurePanel" PreviewMouseDown="ProcedurePanel_OnPreviewMouseDown">
                                    <DockPanel Width="{c:Binding ElementName=MainPanel, Path=Width-40}">
                                        <!--<TextBlock Name="MainText"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Path=title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />-->
                                        <htb:HighlightTextBlock Name="MainText"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Path=title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                            <htb:HighlightTextBlock.HighlightRules>
                                                <htb:HighlightRule
                                                    IgnoreCase="{Binding IgnoreCase, Source={StaticResource SourceVm}}" 
                                                    HightlightedText="{Binding Path=title, Converter={StaticResource getFilter}}">
                                                    <htb:HighlightRule.Highlights>
                                                        <htb:HighlightBackgroung Brush="Yellow"/>
                                                    </htb:HighlightRule.Highlights>
                                                </htb:HighlightRule>
                                            </htb:HighlightTextBlock.HighlightRules>
                                        </htb:HighlightTextBlock>
                                    </DockPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>

                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

A component written by our compatriot with open source is used

[Component](https://github.com/iRumba/HighlightedTextBlock)

[Description of component](https://habrahabr.ru/post/314060/)

The commented code is an old TexBlock with no selection

The new HighlightTextBlock component perfectly selects the text if you use a static resource, as in the example, but when I try to bind it to the current text it can not find this field :(, I'm new in WPF help figure it out

```
HightlightedText="{Binding Path=title, Converter={StaticResource getFilter}}"
```

How correctly to anchor this property to title?

DataContext structure

```
public ObservableCollection<Procedure> Procedures { set; get; }
public CollectionViewSource ProceduresView { set; get; } = new CollectionViewSource();

    ....

    Procedures = new ObservableCollection<Procedure>();

    ProceduresView.Filter += Procedures_Filter;
    ProceduresView.Source = Procedures;

    ....

public class Procedure : ObservableObject 
{
    ....
    public String title { get; set; }
    ....
}
....

// Simple filtering        
void Procedures_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    Procedure procedure = (Procedure) e.Item;
    Boolean flag = false;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
    {
        Setting.Filter sfilter = new Setting.Filter();
        sfilter.type = "искать везде";
        sfilter.text = filter;
        ObservableCollection<Setting.Filter> arr = new ObservableCollection<Setting.Filter>();
        arr.Add(sfilter);
        if (Utils.AssignedProcedureFromFilter(procedure, arr)) flag = true;
    }
    else flag = true;
    e.Accepted = flag;
}
```

[Video with problem description](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7VFqRuc8CpM)

[Simplified project emitting my functional](https://github.com/leganas/TestTextBlock)

On the Russian-speaking forum they explained to me that:

> Your case, in fact, is more serious. DataContext you, apparently, the
>   right one. But your Binding expression is inside the HighlightRules
>   property setter, which is not part of the visual tree (because it is
>   not available as a Child element of your control). And elements that
>   are not inside the visual tree, participate in bindings are only
>   limited: they do not inherit DataContext, nor access by name through
>   ElementName. As a solution, bind to an element via x: Reference. In my
>   (heavily cut) test case, HightlightedText = "{Binding Path =
>   DataContext.title, Source = {x: Reference MainText}} is triggered."
>   But, if directly replaced by this, a strange error works: 'Can not
>   call MarkupExtension. ProvideValue because of a cyclic dependency. The
>   properties inside the MarkupExtension can not reference objects that
>   reference the MarkupExtension result.

The workaround for the error was found here: you need to put your element in resources. We get this:
XAML, modified according to the recommendations

```
<ListBox Name="ProcedureList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProceduresView.View}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Name="ProcedurePanel" PreviewMouseDown="ProcedurePanel_OnPreviewMouseDown">
                <DockPanel Width="{c:Binding ElementName=MainPanel, Path=Width-40}">
                    <!--<TextBlock Name="MainText"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Path=title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />-->
                                                <htb:HighlightTextBlock Name="MainText" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" 
                                                                        Text="{Binding Path=title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                        <htb:HighlightTextBlock.Resources>
                                            <htb:HighlightRule x:Key="HR"
                                                       IgnoreCase="{Binding IgnoreCase, Source={StaticResource SourceVm}}" 
                                                       HightlightedText="{Binding Path=DataContext.title, Source={x:Reference MainText}, Converter={StaticResource getFilter}}">
                                                       <htb:HighlightRule.Highlights>
                                                            <htb:HighlightBackgroung Brush="Yellow"/>
                                                       </htb:HighlightRule.Highlights>
                                            </htb:HighlightRule>
                                            </htb:HighlightTextBlock.Resources>
                                                    <htb:HighlightTextBlock.HighlightRules>
                                                        <htb:HighlightRulesCollection>
                                                            <StaticResource ResourceKey="HR"/>
                                                        </htb:HighlightRulesCollection>
                                                    </htb:HighlightTextBlock.HighlightRules>
                                                </htb:HighlightTextBlock>
                </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I was given advice on the restructuring of XAML, through resources, this partially solved the problem (I successfully got the title text in the converter), but the element ceased to perform its functions (allocation) During the discussion, it was suggested that the component itself should be finalized

> @iRumba: In theory, the whole trick should not be necessary if you put
>   the HighlighRule collection (also) in a visual tree. Then the
>   DataContext will be automatically inherited and on idea the binding
>   through ElementName too will work.
>
> @iRumba: I do not remember exactly. It seems, it is necessary to
>   specify to add all HighlightRule as LogicalChildren (for this purpose
>   on idea it is necessary to redefine protected internal override
>   IEnumerator LogicalChildren). This is a complicated, advanced
>   technique, yes.

Sorry for Google Translator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution

```
 public class SearchHightlightTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    public SearchHightlightTextBlock() : base() { }

    public String SearchText
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(SearchTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SearchTextProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnDataChanged(DependencyObject source,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock tb = (TextBlock)source;

        if (tb.Text.Length == 0)
            return;

        string textUpper = tb.Text.ToUpper();
        String toFind = ((String)e.NewValue).ToUpper();
        int firstIndex = textUpper.IndexOf(toFind);
        String firstStr = "";
        String foundStr = "";
        if (firstIndex != -1)
        {
            firstStr = tb.Text.Substring(0, firstIndex);
            foundStr = tb.Text.Substring(firstIndex, toFind.Length);
        }
        String endStr = tb.Text.Substring(firstIndex + toFind.Length,
            tb.Text.Length - (firstIndex + toFind.Length));

        tb.Inlines.Clear();
        tb.FontSize = 16;
        var run = new Run();
        run.Text = firstStr;
        tb.Inlines.Add(run);
        run = new Run();
        run.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
        run.Text = foundStr;
        tb.Inlines.Add(run);
        run = new Run();
        run.Text = endStr;

        tb.Inlines.Add(run);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SearchTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SearchText",
            typeof(String),
            typeof(SearchHightlightTextBlock),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnDataChanged));
}
```

Use

```
<parser:SearchHightlightTextBlock SearchText="{Binding Path=title, Converter={StaticResource getFilter}}" Text="{Binding title}"/>
```